# Running maven+eclipse from command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I have created a maven project in eclipse with the below pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.omniture.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>Omniture</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I wanted to run the JUnit test case through command line.
Here is the path for junit test case:

```
/Users/support/Documents/Omniture/src/test/java/com/testOmnitureSelenium
```

Comment: Doesn't running `package` automatically run JUnit Tests before doing a build?

Comment: i am a new bee to this. :) So please guide me in running this

Comment: I am telling you that maven automatically runs unit tests for you when you run package. There no more guiding I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mvn test -Dtest=<testclass>
```

If you want to run a given test class, The above will do it for you. However, as noted, maven will run tests automatically, when you invoke the package goal, rendering the command above to the dark corners of wizards, where mortals need not tread.

Comment: Should also have voted it up...